# How can I take a textbox text entry and make it a variable?

Tags: apt, application-development, python, quickly

I am having trouble with Python and would like to have some help.

I am making a apt GUI 'front-end' with a nice UI.

```
    def on_textbox_changed(self):
        self.instvar = self.installapps.get_text()

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        print "Preparing to run 'sudo apt-get install (package selected)"
        command2 = 'xterm -e sudo apt-get install ' and self.instvar
        cmd2 = commands.getoutput(command2)
```

Would you know how to take a textbox entry and make it a variable? I looked around the web and this is what I came up with. And every time I'm trying this it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rareshn/Documents/Zintori/Applets/aptfe/aptfe/AptfeWindow.py", line 49, in on_button1_clicked
    command2 = 'xterm -e sudo apt-get install ' and self.instvar
AttributeError: 'AptfeWindow' object has no attribute 'instvar'
```

If you could help me, that would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are clicking the button before `self.instvar` is set. The `on_textbox_changed` handler is probably never called. Startup Glade and select your text entry. In the property editor on the right select the `signals` tab and connect the `GtkEditable` `changed` signal to the correct handler.

You should also put a print statement inside `on_textbox_changed` to see if it really is called.

Alse, this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
command2 = 'xterm -e sudo apt-get install ' and self.instvar
```

See this interactive session:

```
>>> instvar = "firefox"
>>> "xterm -e sudo apt-get install" and instvar    # Your code, wrong output
'firefox'
>>> "xterm -e sudo apt-get install %s" % instvar    # Choose one of these
'xterm -e sudo apt-get install firefox'
>>> "xterm -e sudo apt-get install " + instvar
'xterm -e sudo apt-get install firefox'
>>> "xterm -e sudo apt-get install {}".format(instvar)
'xterm -e sudo apt-get install firefox'
```